# Append list only when change is detected in while true loop. Or extract sequences from list

Tags: python, list, opencv

I'm using opencv with python to truncate input video based on when motion is detected.

Once the motion detection part of the code works the next step is to find the in/out edit points on which to make the cuts (I'm using ffmpeg).

The method that I've used works well for when there is only one period of motion:

```
    If motion occurs:
       append list with time information
```

Then min(list) and max(list) are used to find the cut times.

However, this method falls down if there are two or more isolated periods of motion. Say if the list reads [2,3,4,34,35,36], the edit points would be:

```
min(list) = 2
max(list) = 36
```

where I want a way of extracting the continuous timing information, so in this example: 2-4 and 34-36.

It's this logic that I'm stuck with!

I have tried appending a new list to a list of lists when there is no action but a new list is created on each iteration of the while loop (or each frame that registers as no motion) where I only want a new list on the transition from motion to no motion.

```
    If motion occurs:
       append list with time information

    else:
      append list_of_list #but only once. not every iteration without motion
```

Another way of doing it might be to add 0 to the list when no motion occurs:

```
    If motion occurs:
       append list with time information

    else:
      append list with 0
```

Using the previous example, this would instead give:

[0,0,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0, ...,0,0,0,0,0,34,35,36,0,0,0,0,0,0...]

Is there a convenient way of extracting the sequences 2-4 and 34-36 out of a single list?

I hope that's clear. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This a little unclear to me: how do you get the list in the first place? What would the desired result look like for two motion periods? An easy way to add the list only once is ``elif list_of_list[-1]: list_of_list.append([])`` because you'll add a new empty list only if the last entry is not an empty one (i.e. only if the previous iteration was not a "no-motion" period)

Comment: For one motion period the first list is written to using, l.append(seconds). This adds the time in seconds to the list every frame period where motion is detected. Example output:  >>>print l >>> [3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6] #numbers = time in seconds.

Comment: For two (or more) motion periods the subsequent lot of timing information should be held in a subsequent list. e.g. >>>print list_of_lists >>>[[3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6],[17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19]] It's this that stumps me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from the comments, I think what you want is a list of intervals of continuous motion, e.g. `[ [2,5], [8,12], [15,16] ]`.

This can be obtained using the following code:

```
lst = [[]]

while True:
    # get second
    if lst[-1]:
        last = lst[-1][1]
        if second - last == 1:
            lst[-1][1] = second
        elif second - last > 1:
            lst.append([second, second])
    else:
        lst[-1] = [second, second]
```